# jQuery Clone and select2 events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have created two hidden fields where I am adding array to make dropdown. select2 array are depending on the first select2. So when I select in first select2 I will call select2 event to filter another select2.

All this is working correct. But I am cloning also same. But I don't know how to clone event of select2. I could not filter also. Somebody can help

My Sample code
My jsbin https://jsbin.com/monusupuni/edit?html,js,output

```
<div class="midcontainer pad20">
    <div class="content-area fullWidth whiteBg">
        <div class="pad15">
            <div class="flightRows">
                <div class="row flightRow">
                    <p><strong><span id="lbFlight">Flight 1</span></strong></p>
                    <div class="depCol1">
                        <label for="seldcity1" id="lbDeptCity"></label><br>
                        <input type="hidden" id="seldcity1" name="seldcity1" class="styled wth190 seldcity" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="depCol2">
                        <label for="selacity1" id="lbArrivalCity"></label><br>
                        <input type="hidden" id="selacity1" name="selacity1" style="width: 210px;" class="styled wth190 selacity" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="depCol1">
                        <label for="selddate1" id="lbDeptDate"></label><br />
                        <input name="selddate1" type="text" id="selddate1" autocomplete="off" class="datepicker calIcon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="searchBtnHolder"><a href="#" class="addFlightBtn">Add another Flight</a></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your exact desire. Still, did you know that jQuery clone() method takes 2 arguments: withDataAndEvent and deepWithDataAndEvent.

So when you use .clone(), it will only clone the element, not the event associated with. You'll need to use .clone(true,true) to copy all events attached.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Issue is not that, issue is that event which I have define that is not getting clone